# How to make a parameter take a pseudo "null" value depending on the context in OCAML

Tags: ocaml

I want to make a function that takes a list and an operator and do that operation on all elements of that list.

The problem is that while making an auxiliary function I don't know how to initialise the additional parameter to the "NULL" of the datatype that the function will take as input.

For example if we are dealing with ints I would like my parameter to take value 0, 0. with floats and for a String "".

Thanks in advance !

```
let rec combine_all_aux (va:'a) (op:'a -> 'a -> 'a) (li:'a list) (ret:'a) = match li with
  | [] -> va
  | h :: t -> combine_all_aux va op t (op ret h)
;;

let combine_all va op li =
  combine_all_aux va op li (Something)
;;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing I notice is that your code, as given, always returns `va`. When it gets down to the end of the list it ignores the accumulated value `ret`.

Because of this, it's difficult to understand exactly what the function is supposed to do. Should we consider `va` to be at the end of the list, or at the beginning? Are you implementing a right fold or a left fold?

Let's say you're implementing a left fold and that `va` is supposed to be at the end of the list. Then the call:

```
combine_all va op [e1; e2; e3]
```

is equivalent to this expression (using + to represent the `op` parameter):

```
(((e1 + e2) + e3) + va)
```

If this is what you're aiming for, one solution that occurs to me is to consider the list `li @ [va]`. This list is non-empty by construction. Therefore you can always extract the head of the list and use it as your initial accumulated value (which you call `ret`). You then apply your recursive function to the tail of `li @ [va]`.

If `va` should instead be considered to be at the beginning of the list, things are even easier. You already have the head and tail of the non-empty list of operands: `va` is the head, and `li` is the tail.

Comment: `va` is the value returned when the list is empty, using the head as the accumulated value could work indeed, I will try that

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Jeffrey I wrote the function using the head as the accumulator which removes the need for an additional parameter.

```
let rec combine_all_aux (va:'a) (op:'a -> 'a -> 'a) (li:'a list) = match li with
  | [] -> va
  | h :: t -> op h (combine_all_aux va op t)
;;
```